# Why my firebase website can not display image blocks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

First, I'm sorry that my English is not good.

I'm making some open source program to show cardnews.

Our project github link : [link1](https://github.com/HyeJinP/os_second_project)

and

hosted website link : [link2](https://os-cardnews.firebaseapp.com/).

In html, if I click cardnews (for example: first box(Welcome to ERICAST 1)), then I can see image block in new page.

But in website, I can not see any image block.

slide/a.html is https://os-cardnews.firebaseapp.com/slide/a.html.

I want to show code to you, but I'm first time at here, then I can't do that. I'm sorry.

How to show Image block in website??

Comment: your jquery has not loaded correctly. the error says `the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your script tag with `https` inside `a.html`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is okay that a, c, d, and e. but there is still a problem with b.

Comment: it looks like you have same problem in a.html. `https` error